# Flutter syncable from server Grid based map

Tags: flutter, firebase, dictionary, grid

I'm trying to build small project, however got stuck on the building 2d map which is grid-like thing (Cartesian coordinate system, i'm not sure what is the right name for it) where each square is a section that can hold some information, later on when filled with information - should be exported somehow and saved to the database (i'm gonna use firebase)

So i need to generate json-ish thing for each square coordinates so later on I can build this map in some sort of canvas.

Idea is having 2 app modes - editor and viewer.
Editor will be paining this squares for now let's just stick to colours but later on this will be real assets. Now i understand that storing asset in a json is a dumb idea, so i want to create something like:

```
{
x: 10,
y: 10,
color:red
}
```

and after painting needed amount of squares it will be saved to database so viewer will be able to render it an display.

Now I'm not really sure if its good idea to do in flutter, however I want to mess around with it, and don't know what is the best way to do it - using Flame? Canvas? Some sort of painter or `grid` thing. So let me know if you have any ideas, would really appreciate any help or advice